# Strange behavior with localizeddate filter in Twig

Tags: date, filter, twig

In Twig, I have a DateTime like that (from a `dump`):

```
DateTime {#22261 ▼
  +"date": "2017-01-01 08:00:00.000000"
  +"timezone_type": 1
  +"timezone": "+01:00"
}
```

When I print this date with different filters, I get different results for the year.

Examples :

```
{{ testdate|date('d M Y') }}
```

prints `01 Jan 2017` => Year is correct.

```
{{ testdate|localizeddate('none', 'none', "fr", "Europe/Paris", "d MMM YYYY") }}
```

prints `1 janv. 2016` => Year is **wrong**.

```
{{ testdate|localizeddate('medium', 'none', "fr") }}
```

prints `1 janv. 2017` => Year is correct.

So when I use `localizeddate('none', 'none', "fr", "Europe/Paris", "d MMM YYYY")` the year seems to be wrong.

If I change locale to "en", the year is now correct (2017). But if I try in other locales like "de", "it", "es", "pl" year is always "2016".

Note : Same results if I let `null` for timezone parameter.

Answer (score 4):

http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

You must use 'y' instead of 'Y'.

With 'Y' you will show the year of the week, but with 'y' you will show the correct year.

Sometimes, a short week in january is considered part of december (week 52 or 53) and vice versa.